# Freeradius accounting filter

Tags: freeradius, accounting

How to configure accounting filter?
For example, there are two types of users:

```
    jack@gmail.com
    anna@yahoo.com
    123qwer-user
```

It is necessary that only the user `jack@google.com` and `anna@yahoo.com`. I have tried to write regex to the accounting section, but it didn’t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string filter with "=~" in if condition of the authorize section. Note that you can only apply this to only string so use attribute value in string like %{User-Name}

you can use simple regular expression like "[\w-]+@([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+" for comparison

I do not have an instance running currently to try, Will spin one soon and try and update the actual condition.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don’t quite understand where should I add the regular expression?
I registered it in the accounting section to sql, but nothing has changed, all users are recorded in the database.